# Weave inline typecasting (python)

Tags: c++, python, casting, numpy, scipy

best wishes for 2013!

I'm using SciPy's weave inline with some C++ code of mine to transpose huge matrices (about 200.000 x 15). It works like a charm, but I have a question about typecasting:

My input matrix is read from a file, comma separated etc., so all the entries are strings rather than floats ('0.551' rather than 0.551). This doesn't affect the way the transpose function works, but later on I have to convert certain rows into numpy float arrays anyways, so I was wondering if this could be done in the C++ code instead. Let me explain with some code:

```
def transpose(lines, N, x):
    code =  """
            py::list matrix;
            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                py::list line;
                if(i == 1) { continue; }
                for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    line.append(lines[j][i]);
                }
                matrix.append(line);
            }
            return_val = matrix;
            """
    return weave.inline(code, ['lines', 'N', 'x'])

matrix = [['0.5','0.1'],['0.2','0.2']]
matrixT = transpose(matrix, len(matrix), len(matrix[0]))
final_result = np.array(matrixT[0], dtype=float)
```

In the example my small matrix will be transposed and my example result will be the first row of the transposed matrix converted to a numpy array of dtype float. Can this be done in C++ code instead? I've tried using `double x = (double) lines[j][i]` and things like that, but it somehow doesn't work for appending to a py::list object.

Comment: I tried your example adding an `atof` in the appending, i.e. `line.append(atof(lines[j][i]))`, and it works nicely.

Comment: Why aren't you using `numpy`'s builtin functionality here?  `arr = np.arr([['0.5','0.1'],['0.2','0.2']],dtype=float)` and then to transpose:  `arr.T`, although you don't have to transpose to get the first row:  `arr[:,0]` should do that.  There's also [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) for reading data from csv-like files...

Comment: Numpy's built-in methods are too slow, I've tried genfromtxt and loadtxt, but they take about twice the time that my C++ algorithm takes. @Jaime this was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Would it also be possible to return the output as a numpy 2d array rather than a python list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following can do the whole thing you are after:

```
def transpose(lines):
    code =  """
            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    out[j + i * N] = atof(lines[j][i]);
                    // OUT2(i, j) = atof(lines[j][i]);
                }
            }
            """
    N = len(lines)
    x = len(lines[0])
    out = np.empty((x, N), dtype=np.float64)
    weave.inline(code, ['lines', 'N', 'x', 'out'])
    return out

>>> matrix = [['0.5', '0.1', '0.7'],['0.2','0.2', '0.4']]
>>> matrix
[['0.5', '0.1', '0.7'], ['0.2', '0.2', '0.4']]
>>> transpose(matrix)
array([[ 0.5,  0.2],
       [ 0.1,  0.2],
       [ 0.7,  0.4]])
```

Aside from constantly forgetting `;` after something like 6 years without writing any C, I had a lot of trouble figuring out what `out` was turning into inside the C++ code, and in the end it is a pointer to the data itself, not to a `PyArrayObject` as the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/weave.html#type-conversions) states. There are two variables defined by weave that are available for use, `out_array` and `py_out`, which are of type `PyArrayObject*` and `PyObject*` respectively.

I have left an alternative version of the assignment commented out: weave automatically defines macros `<VAR>1`, `<VAR>2`, `<VAR>3`, and `<VAR>4` to access items of arrays of the corresponding number of dimensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is indeed exactly what I needed and it is a bit faster than anything I've tried before.